# Error 200 when creating new table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm running on a local server with uWamp on mySql 5.6.11 and with php 5.6.18,
however i have an error when i'm tring to create new table on Phpmyadmin.

***I did check the logs and here is what it is saying when I create a new base :***

> 1# InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/innodb_index_stats from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
>
> 2# InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/innodb_table_stats from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
>
> 3# InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_master_info from the internal data 
>   dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
>
> 4# InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_relay_log_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
>
> 5#  InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_worker_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.

***However the new base is created but I can't create new table, it's show me an error message which is "ERROR : 200"; and here are the messages on the logs :***

> 1# InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/innodb_index_stats from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
>
> 2# InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/innodb_table_stats from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
>
> 3# InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_master_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
>
> 4#  InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_relay_log_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
>
> 5# InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_worker_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
>
> 6# InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/innodb_index_stats from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
>
> 7# InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/innodb_table_stats from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
>
> 8# InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_master_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
>
> 9# InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_relay_log_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists.
>
> 10# InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/slave_worker_info from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists

I have really no idea, already checked some issue on google but I didn't found an issue for my problem

Comment: Did you delete those tables before recreating them in that DB?

Comment: Offtopic. Not really a programing questions. We're not general DB tech support. Try the DBA site, maybe.

Comment: Do you or have you had a database corrution/crash? Looks like it to me

Comment: It's a new environnement, the DB was never used before. I even tried to delete and recreate the DB but it doesn't work.

@MarcB i know, i just wanna start working bro

Comment: what's the relation to php though? folder/file/path issue maybe? permissions? hard to say here.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i don't think so, or i didn't noticed it

Comment: Actually those errors are reporting that MYSQL cannot find its own databases. The ones that it uses to look after itself with. That MYSQL is nukked, or has been badly installed

Comment: BozeLouf Bkl:
This should help you: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48166/cannot-open-table-mysql-innodb-index-stats

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well I have no idea, how can I check this ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is probably true, I didn't touched any code or database since two years

Comment: could be something in the `.frm` file(s). Make sure it exists and using the correct file and that the data that's in there is correct. If you're using include/require etc.

Comment: Well i just uninstaled uWamp and installed it back it's working well now

Comment: was a config issue then.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the directory containg these .frm files and make sure they are not write protected etc.